# Non-constant Variables in Gitlab Pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Surely many of you have encountered this and I would like to share my hacky solution. Essentially during the CI / CD process of a Gitlab pipeline most parameters are passed through "Variables". There are two issues that I've encountered with that.

1. Those parameters cannot be altered in Realtime - Say I'd want to execute jobs based on information from previous jobs it would always need to be saved in the cache as opposed to written to CI / CD variables
2. The execution of jobs is evaluated before the script, so the "rules" will only ever apply to the original parameters. Trouble arises when those are only available during runtime.

For complex pipelines one would want to pick and choose the tests automatically without having to respecify parameters every time. In my case I delivered a data product and depending on the content different steps had to be taken. How do we deal with those issues?

1. Changing parameters real-time:
   https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html This API provides users with a way of interacting with the CI / CD variables. This will not work for any variables defined at the head of the YML files under the Variables tag. Rather this is a way to access the "Custom CI/CD Variables" https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-cicd-variables found under this link. This way custom variables can be created altered and deleted during running a pipeline. The only thing needed is a PRIVATE-TOKEN that has access rights to the API (I believe my token has all the rights).

   ```
   job:
     stage: example
     script:
       - 'curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/variables/VARIABLE_NAME" --form "value=abc"'
   ```
2. Onto the next problem. Altering the variables won't let us actually control downstream jobs like this because of the fact that the "rules" block is executed before the pipeline is actually run. Hence it will use the variable before the curl request is sent.

```
job2:
  stage: after_example
  rules:
    - if: $VARIABLE_NAME == "abc"
  script:
    - env
```

The way to avoid that is child pipelines. Child pipelines are initialized inside the parent pipeline and check the environment variables anew. A full example should illustrate my point.

```
variables:
  PARAMETER: "Cant be changed"

stages:
  - example
  - after_example
  - finally

job_1:
  # Changing "VARIABLE_NAME" during runtime to "abc", VARIABLE_NAME has to exist
  stage: example
  script:
    - 'curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/variables/VARIABLE_NAME" --form "value=abc"'

job_2.1:
  # This wont get triggered as we assume "abc" was not the value in VARIABLE_NAME before job_1
  stage: after_example
  rules:
    - if: $VARIABLE_NAME == "abc"
  script:
    - env

job_3:
  stage: after_example
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: .donwstream.yml
    strategy: depend

job_4:
  stage: finally
  script:
    - echo "Make sure to properly clean up your variables to a default value"
```

```
# inside downstream.yml

stages:
  - downstream

job_2.2:
  # This will happen because the pipeline is initialized after job_1
  stage: downstream
  rules:
    - if: $VARIABLE_NAME == "abc"
  script:
    - env
```

This coding bit probably won't run, however it exemplifies my point rather nicely. Job 2 should be executed based on an action that happens in Job 1. While the variables will be updated once we reach job 2.1, the rules check happens before so it will never be executed. Child pipelines do the rule check during the runtime of the Parent pipeline, this is why job 2.2 does run.

This variant is quite hacky and probably really inefficient, but for all intents and purposes it gets the job done.

Comment: This does not seem relevant to the [git] tag at all, remove?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please check out the guide to [ask]. This is not a blog site - [questions do need to be questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/74411/). If you have what you feel is a valuable solution to a common problem which has not already been asked on this site, you can post a question and then [answer it yourself](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/). However, please do not answer the question in the question itself. Thanks!